# How to set css class to a row which has focus in Dojo datagrid

Tags: dojox.grid.datagrid

I am using DOJO datagrid version 1.10 What I want is on tab indexing the row in the grid should get highlighted so that user will be able to know on which row the focus is. But I am not getting the row focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen on the `dojox.grid.DataGrid::onCellFocus` event. The event arguments are the focused `cell`-Object itself and the corresponding `rowIndex`.

```
function onCellFocus(cell, rowIndex) {

  // first clear selection
  grid.selection.clear();

  // select the focused row
  grid.selection.setSelected(rowIndex, true);

  // invoke manually the render method
  grid.render();
}
```

I've created a working fiddle for you, which can be found [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jxtq2k67/).